# Left-align labels in corrplot R

Tags: r, plot, r-corrplot

Assume a dataframe and a correlation plot

```
X <- data.frame("XXXYYY" = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
                "XY" = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
                "XXXY" = rnorm(100, 0, 1))
corrplot::corrplot(cor(X), method = "color", tl.col = "black")
```

is it possible, to left-align the labels on the y-axis as below?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Worth considering a `ggplot` approach where you would have a high degree of control over all aspects of the plot including left-alignment of the y-axis text:

```r
X <- data.frame("XXXYYY" = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
                "XY" = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
                "XXXY" = rnorm(100, 0, 1))

library(tidyverse)
library(corrr)

X |> 
  correlate() |> 
  pivot_longer(-term) |>
  ggplot(aes(term, name, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 0))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-20 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>